# nginx server_name inside stream block possible?

Tags: nginx, proxy, stream, reverse

Current setup as follows:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 9987 udp;

        server_name  subdomain.EXAMPLE.com; # this line is resulting in an error

        proxy_pass localhost:9987;
        proxy_timeout 1s;
        proxy_responses 1;
        error_log logs/dns.log;
    }
}
```

**server_name  subdomain.EXAMPLE.com;**

Is this possible?

```
$nginx -t

$nginx: [emerg] "server_name" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15
```

Works just fine without server_name, but I'd like to use a sub-domain if possible. (I am using a build with *--with-stream*, thats not my issue.)

Comment: An alternative approach that may work for some is to bind against a specific IP address: `listen x.x.x.x:9987 udp`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> TCP has no concept of server names, so this is not possible. It only works
>   in HTTP because the client sends the hostname it is trying to access as
>   part of the request, allowing nginx to match it to a specific server block.

Source: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,263208,263217#msg-263217

Comment: Hello, this seems unexact as another post indicates that Nginx has the ability to read the SNI header in the SSL handshake before passing the request to the upstream server : https://serverfault.com/a/999428

Answer (score 4):

While it is not in the original nginx, it is implemented in a Chinese fork of it via SNI: https://tengine.taobao.org/document/stream_sni.html